# Oracle SQL: Selecting based on value in previous rows columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm curious about writing a SQL query in Oracle based on the previous row in a list of returned rows. Basically I have to query our database for all rows that have a ID # of 2460, but the previous row (sorted by date) has an ID # of 2463. Is there any way to do this?

Sorry if this is confusing or a stupid question I'm very new and not really good at these sort of things. I'll be happy to clarify anything that needs clarifying.

Thanks!

Edit:

Here's the query I'm running based on Gordon's answer along with a screenshot of the results I'm getting vs the results I'm wanting.

```
select *
from (select activitytranledger.*, lag(reasontype) over (order by trandate) as prev_reason from activitytranledger) activitytranledger
where trandate between to_date('02/7/2017','MM/DD/YYYY')
and to_date('02/8/2017','MM/DD/YYYY')
and reasontype = 2460
and prev_reason = 2463
order by trandate
;
```

I'll then take the location # and query it for the specific day.

```
select *
from activitytranledger
where location = 5777
and trandate between to_date('02/7/2017','MM/DD/YYYY') 
and to_date('02/8/2017','MM/DD/YYYY')
order by trandate
;
```

Using the "Transid" I can find the specific row that was output by the first query. However, it does not seem to be giving me the desired results.

[Wanted results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svfCx.jpg) (Notice how the row directly above the row with a "Reasontype" of 2460 has a reason type of 2463)

[Current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxvWs.jpg) (The row I highlighted should have the 2463 in the column I've pointed to)

Edit 2: switched 2463 and 2460

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one interpretation of your question.  Use `lag()` and a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(id) over (order by date) as prev_id
      from t
     ) t
where id = 2463 and prev_id = 2460;
```

Comment: @AdamNeighbors - to explain further, it would be easier if you could use `lag()...` directly in the `where` clause; unfortunately, you can't. The subquery is unavoidable. However, in your formulation you are not selecting from a table - you are selecting from a "list of returned rows". Where this list is built, it is possible that you may add the `lag` function right there and do away with one layer of nested subqueries. (But whether you can do that or not depends on what the query does.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've made a few edits to make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out I'm an idiot. @GordonLinoff's solution worked perfectly I just simply forgot to add the location # to the query below is the final query that I came up with. I'm able to replace the location # with my variable and can now insert it into my loop and it works like a charm. Thanks all that contributed!

```
select *
from (select activitytranledger.*, lag(reasontype) over (order by trandate) as
prev_reason from activitytranledger) activitytranledger
where trandate between to_date('02/7/2017','MM/DD/YYYY')
and to_date('02/8/2017','MM/DD/YYYY')
and location = 5777
and reasontype = 2460
and prev_reason = 2463
order by trandate
;
```